# CSS: 3 column height 100%

Tags: html, fluid-layout, css

Here is an example page:

http://jsfiddle.net/SkeLLLa/pwfH2/

I want to set 100% height for the `content` class (see the "Problem here" comment in the CSS source), but when I do this left and right columns (nested in the `content` div) become `0px` height. But when `content` has height set in pixels it works fine.

Are there any solutions without JavaScript?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4515251/holy-grail-layout-with-100-height

Comment: From another "Matthew": http://www.alistapart.com/articles/holygrail/

Comment: Adding 
`padding-bottom:9999px;
margin-bottom:-9999px;`

to left and right columns helped. Thanks!

Comment: But those tricks cause scroll to appear. As for other examples - I need "center" element placed under "left" and "right" columns and center element shouldn't contain any margins to draw fancy rounded borders.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `display: inline-block` for the columns and  `height:100%` for the `html` and `body` tags:

```html
    <!doctype html>
    <html>
      <head>
      <style>
      html, body, #content, #left, #right, #center { height: 100%; }
      #content { width: 100%; }
      #left, #center, #right { display:inline-block; }
      #left, #center, #right { width: 32%; border: 1px solid red; }
 
      /* media query for IE 6-7 */
      @media, 
        { 
        #left, #center, #right { display:inline; }
        }
      </style>
      </head>
      <body>
        <div id="content">
            <div id="left">foo</div>
            <div id="center">bar</div>
            <div id="right">baz</div>
        </div>
      </body>
    </html>
```