# 3 columns + 100% height

Tags: css, html

I need same as in the http://blog.html.it/layoutgala/LayoutGala19.html but height of each column should be 100% and height of whole page should be min 100%. Can anybody help?

Comment: Have you tried adding `height: 100%` in the css?

Comment: There are so many ways to do this it's not even funny. Look in the right column with the header **Related**: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10086007/css-3-column-height-100?rq=1

Comment: Lets play a little bit http://jsfiddle.net/2wdeB/2/. Looks good but if we will resize our window then we will get http://i.imgur.com/5x1HxME.png?1. So this is not good

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should probably look at the question: [How to have multiple columns that consume 100% height using twitter bootstrap?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10239534/how-to-have-multiple-columns-that-consume-100-height-using-twitter-bootstrap)

They mention this [link](http://fiddle.jshell.net/teresko/EkTVv/show/) (and you can see the source code [here](http://jsfiddle.net/teresko/UG8Rk/)) that I think is what you are looking for. You have to set `height: 100%` for `<html>` and `<body>`, and then, the container should have a `min-height: 100%`

Comment: http://fiddle.jshell.net/teresko/EkTVv/show/
Your example looks good. I see there is padding-bottom, margin-bottom technique as well. I will try to apply it for my issue.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Completed examples special for my issue: http://fiddle.jshell.net/2wdeB/6/show/light/ and  http://jsfiddle.net/2wdeB/6/

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to get this layout by using CSS grid, but unfortunately I don't think its possible.  Using floats is an easy way to do this.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body, html {
  height: 100%;
}

.box {
  height: 100%;
}

.box1 {
  float: left;
  width: 20%;
  background-color: red;

}

.box2 {
  float: left;
  width: 60%;
  background-color: green;

}

.box3 {
  float: left;
  width: 20%;
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <body>
    <div class="box box1"></div>
    <div class="box box2"></div>
    <div class="box box3"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Then the text can be placed in each column exactly where you want, using absolute/relative positioning.

EDIT: You can also use [Flexbox](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43988319/9599554) to do this pretty easily.