# Set height of <div> = to height of another <div> through .css

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have two `<div>` elements. Right now my simplified .css is thus:

```
#leftdiv {
    /*this is the navigation pane*/
    min-height: 600px;
    max-height: 600px;
}
#rightdiv {
    /*this is the primary pane*/
    min-height: 600px;
    max-height: 600px;
    overflow-y: auto;
}
```

I've set a hard min- and max-heights for both so they keep the same height, and if content overflows out of the `#rightdiv`, a scrollbar appears. I'd like this scrollbar to be gone and having the `#rightdiv` and `#leftdiv` stretch to fit the contents of the `#rightdiv`. I want the whole site to stretch height-wise to fit the contents, but if I remove the `overflow-y: auto;` from my .css and remove the max-heights, the `#rightdiv` stretches, but the `#leftdiv` doesn't, yielding some truly ugly design.

I'd like something like the below:

```
#leftdiv {
    min-height: equal to #rightdiv height if #rightdiv is taller, else 600px;
}
#rightdiv {
    min-height: equal to #leftdiv height if #leftdiv is taller, else 600px;
}
```

How would I go about setting the min-height of both like this?

Comment: Are you OK with using Javascript?

Comment: Absolutely, although I'd prefer not to use jQuery if possible.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I am assuming that you have used height attribute at both so i am comparing it with a height
left do it with JavaScript.

```
var right=document.getElementById('rightdiv').style.height;
var left=document.getElementById('leftdiv').style.height;
if(left>right)
{
    document.getElementById('rightdiv').style.height=left;
}
else
{
    document.getElementById('leftdiv').style.height=right;
}
```

Another idea can be found here
[HTML/CSS: Making two floating divs the same height](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1205159/html-css-making-two-floating-divs-the-same-height).

Comment: hope I'm not saying anything silly, but this doesn't work if you have padding or borders on only one of the left/right divs. They will add to the outside height of the div.

Comment: @JRobinss any example to prove what you are saying?

Comment: No, but after reading your question I poked around... consider [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10787782/full-height-of-a-html-element-div-including-border-padding-and-margin) which says that what I would be looking for would be [offsetHeight](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/offsetHeight), not [height](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/height). See also [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSS_Object_Model/Determining_the_dimensions_of_elements). Hope this helps.

Comment: (BTW, after reading some stuff online I ended up using `display:table` as in the other answer, but I did try your code! ;-) )

Answer (score 24):

If you don't care for IE6 and IE7 users, simply use `display: table-cell` for your divs:

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/CTsFF/)

Note the use of wrapper with `display: table`.

For IE6/IE7 users - if you have them - you'll probably need to fallback to Javascript.

Comment: Best solution, Javascript is absolute overkill in this case.

Answer (score 4):

If you're open to using javascript then you can get the property on an element like this: `document.GetElementByID('rightdiv').style.getPropertyValue('max-height');`

And you can set the attribute on an element like this: `.setAttribute('style','max-height:'+heightVariable+';');`

Note: if you're simply looking to set both element's `max-height` property in one line, you can do so like this:

```
#leftdiv,#rightdiv
{
    min-height: 600px;   
}
```

Comment: it's possible to achieve this using pure CSS, see my answer.

Comment: Ah, totally forgot about good ole `display:table`.  Thanks for that; will edit my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

You would certainly benefit from using a responsive framework for your project. It would save you a good amount of headaches. However, seeing the structure of your HTML I would do the following:

Please check the example:
http://jsfiddle.net/xLA4q/

HTML:

```
<div class="nav-content-wrapper">
 <div class="left-nav">asdasdasd ads asd ads asd ad asdasd ad ad a ad</div>
 <div class="content">asd as dad ads ads ads ad ads das ad sad</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.nav-content-wrapper{position:relative; overflow:auto; display:block;height:300px;}
.left-nav{float:left;width:30%;height:inherit;}
.content{float:left;width:70%;height:inherit;}
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems like what you're looking for is a variant on the [CSS Holy Grail Layout](http://matthewjamestaylor.com/blog/ultimate-3-column-holy-grail-pixels.htm), but in two columns. Check out the resources at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4515251/holy-grail-layout-with-100-height) for more information.