# Twitter Bootstrap equal height columns and content aligned bottom

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

i am using Twitter Bootstrap 3 for laying out a site and I need to achieve something specific.  I have a two column layout with an image on the left and some text on the right...

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-6">
      <img class="img-responsive" src="http://dummyimage.com/600x400/000/fff">
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-6">
      <p>
          This is some dummy content              
      </p>
  </div>
</div>

<style>    
.colright{background:green;color:white;}
</style>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/52VtD/9054/

I would like the text in the right hand column to be positioned at the bottom of the column, but I would also like the column to always be an equal height of the one on the left.

Comment: For the height part, check out this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19484544/set-height-of-div-to-height-of-another-div-through-css

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To get that layout you will need to break the `float` rules of bootstrap. Try this:

- Add a class on the row to later target the columns:

  ```
  <div class="row t-cell">
  ```
- Then with CSS use `table-cell` like this:

  ```
  .t-cell > div {
      display:table-cell;
      float:none;
      vertical-align:bottom;
  }
  ```

Check this **[DemoFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/52VtD/9055/)**

Comment: I know this is a very old question.. Going by you answer the responsiveness of the grid is lost. If that is the case why use the grid in the 1st place ?

Comment: Hi @pravin you have a valid point I think OP can answer this better..... But I guess the use of the class names for the grid like the `col-xs-6` gives you some other properties you keep like the `width -- padding -- position` inherited from bootstrap css