# Equale height on col div in bootstrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to align heights on some row columns using bootstrap.

I would like to set my right div same height as multiple others.

Please see this: http://www.bootply.com/pLl07GPKmv

Comment: Possible duplicate - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26911175/twitter-bootstrap-equal-height-columns-and-content-aligned-bottom

Answer (score 0):

Remove the class `"setHeight"` from the div whose size you want to shrink.