# How to get same height to two sibling buttons

Tags: css, html

I have two `<button>` elements inside a `<div>` element. Other button has a lot of text that is divided into two or more rows, and other has a little text (one row). How can I give the same height for both buttons?

I'm not trying to get a Javascript or jQuery etc-based answer, but a clean and neet css-based answer, and I'm not trying to animate or manipulate thease elements.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Set height of <div> = to height of another <div> through .css](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19484544/set-height-of-div-to-height-of-another-div-through-css)

Comment: r u looking like this? http://jsfiddle.net/eaeLfL50/

Comment: @SureshPonnukalai, yes, thank you. You could create an answer based on it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on my comments fiddle, you can apply buttons display property to `table-cell` and achieve the same.

**HTML**

```
 <div class="test">
    <button>small text</button>
    <button>this is big text and will go to new line</button>
 </div>
```

**CSS**

```
 .test{display:table;}
 button{width:90px; height:110%; margin:0px 10px; vertical-align:top; display:table-cell;}
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/eaeLfL50/1/)

Answer (score -2):

You can adjust the padding top and bottom.
Visit http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_padding.asp

Comment: This won't work if your text in the button spans multiple lines

Comment: you are right, it will work with height property and percentance