# Set (responsive) height of <img> = to height of another <img>

Tags: javascript, css

I have an image id="img1" with "width=100%;height:auto".
And another image id="img2"  ... in an almost un-related parentage, that needs to be fixed width but the same height as img1.

I found here:
[[Set height of <div> = to height of another <div> through .css](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19484544/set-height-of-div-to-height-of-another-div-through-css][1])
that:

> If you're open to using javascript then you can get the property on an
>   element like this:
>   document.GetElementByID('rightdiv').style.getPropertyValue('max-height');
>
> And you can set the attribute on an element like this:
>   .setAttribute('style','max-height:'+heightVariable+';');

So I tried:

```
var imgHeight = GetElementByID('img1').style.getPropertyValue('height');
.setAttribute('style','height:'+imgheight+'px';');
```

First issue is how to get it to work.
Second is, would it resize when visitor resizes/rotates their device?

Comment: add it to "on document ready" and "on window resize"

Comment: `GetElementByID` should be `getElementById` and should be preceded by `document.`. The `.setAttribute` will not work because you closed the variable: `;`. Also, no, it will not adjust on resize. You'll have to create an event handler for window resize and put the code inside it for that to make it work.

Answer (score 2):

You need to get the second element in a similar way as you got the first one before you can apply `setAttribute` to it. However, you need to add `document` before your `getElementById` function.

Also, please note that `GetElementByID` will not work. Quote from the [official docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById):

> The capitalization of "Id" in the name of this method must be correct
>   for the code to function; getElementByID() is not valid and will not
>   work, however natural it may seem.

It was also possible to write the `height` of the image a bit more simply, by just using `.height` instead of your original code.

To get it to resize when the user resizes the window, put all that code inside a function and then add two event listeners, one that fires upon loading the page and another that fires upon resize.

Here is the complete code:

```
window.addEventListener("load", resizeImage);
window.addEventListener("resize", resizeImage);

function resizeImage(){
   var imgHeight = document.getElementById('img1').height;
   document.getElementById('img2').height = imgHeight;
}
```